# Backend for StatsD

Tags: backend, statsd

I have heard that we can create our own backend for StatsD.
Is it possible?? If yes, then please guide me about how it is done.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed possible. You can find an example of 3 backends in the [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/tree/master/backends) project on [github.com](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/tree/master/backends).

```
 https://github.com/etsy/statsd/tree/master/backends
```

As for a guide on how to do so the best option, would be to read over those 3 example as it really depends on where your hoping to send the data on how to write the backend for statsd.

In the examples there is 2 examples of a sending the data over a remote socket and one example  writing the output to a file ( console ).

Comment: I would love to find a rrdtool backend